# Shaping the shape tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I looked around on meta but can't seem to find a question about this, so here goes.

Posting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733937/eigenvalues-of-shape-operator-and-of-curvature-on-second-exterior-power) this evening, I looked for a [shape-operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape-operator) tag. This tag wasn't present, but I saw [shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape), which currently has no guidance or tag wiki. I tried to look at the questions to figure out what it was for, but I don't seem to find a pattern. Mostly it seems to be used for "simple" questions about… well, "shapes".

What can we write as a tag wiki?

Comment: That's a really bad tag, wow. Since it clearly conveys different meanings to different people, it seems pretty useless as an organizational tool. I'd vote for it to go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag serves no purpose to anyone. It doesn't fit the standard purposes for tags: filtering and searchability.

It should be incinerated.

<s>Currently, [13 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bshape%5D+is%3Aq) have [shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape) as their only tag, so these should be handled before it is removed.</s>

All questions only having [shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape) as a tag having been handled, I believe it can be burned automatically now.

---

Edit: There has been no decision as to burning or synonymising [shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape), but I feel it'd be a shame not to press on now that we're so close to sorting it out. So whichever one it will be I don't care too much, but please pull the trigger.

Comment: Seen as most retagged questions are now tagged [tag:geometry] (plus other tags), maybe making it synonymous would be a good idea? So those who look for [tag:shape] for a question about a "shape" are redirected to [tag:geometry]?

Comment: I'm not too sure what to do with [this one](math.stackexchange.com/questions/454937/rotate-shape-on-a-graph), but the rest of the currently [tag:shape]-tagged questions should be fine with [tag:geometry] instead, so I suggest synonymization.

Comment: I suggest to not worry. One question with a slightly peculiar tag is nothing uncommon and IMO there are more pressing issues on this site to spend time on solving. With the current status, I'm indifferent as to burning or synonymising.

Comment: The quickest way to deal with it would be to make it a synonym and merge. Is there any option other than [tag:geometry] that should be considered for that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Not to me. It also seems in line with the usage of more specific tags like [tag:circle] and [tag:polygons] which tend to be accompanied by [tag:geometry].

Comment: And it's history.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel!